# Rotation with constraints

Tags: modeling

this is my first time asking you a question. I have this blender project which I'm trying to make a foldable stair using constraints but can't find any solution on how it can be rotated to fold as you can see in the picture.

[image]
[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to animate the steps coming in and out of the wall? Or you're saying you want the steps to compress towards and away from the wall?

Comment: did you check "curve modifier"? It allows you to curve a set of objects (that comes from the array modifier) by a curve, so you can have a spiral stairs.

Instead if you just need to let the stairs happears from the wall, why do you need rotation? I don't see any rotation in the second screenshot.

Comment: @user1544752 Hi, No I don't want to animate the stair, I just want to control it so that I can reduce the Mesh, right now all I have is two copies of the stair, one is folded and another one is collapsed.

Comment: @sanbaldo Hi, as you can see in the illustration the stair was folded up to the surface of the wall. then to collapse the stair I need to rotate the stairsteps 90deg. as of now, all I have is two copies of the stair, one is folded and another one is collapsed. I want to Rig it so that I can control it to fold or collapse. right now my focus was to render it with no animation. But when I want to render that with animation I want to rig it so that It can animate to fold or collapse.

Comment: You might need to add some annotation to your example renderings. In the first screen capture I see an outline of the steps (possibly inside the wall?), in the sencond I see the steps leading up to the second floor.

Comment: Hi, @user1544752 I just update, my post and put an annotation on my example. and the steps was not inside the wall, the step was just folded along the surface of the wall.

Comment: You're likely going to need each step as its own object, and set the origin point at the point it's going to rotate around. Then a good place to start is to choose a "Control" step (or use an empty), and on all the other steps, add a "Copy Rotation" constraint with the control step/empty as the target, from local space to local space.

Comment: Hi @TheTrueJard I've tried that earlier and it works, but now the problem is the beam, the steps were correctly rotating to 90deg using an empty, but the beam didn't move to the right place. I've tried the transformation tool so that when I rotate the empty at the same time the beam move to its correct position when collapse, it moves but cant find the right spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out, here's the overall setup (will all origin points showing):

[image: stairs1]

[image: stairs2]

The empty at the bottom left is the controller and can be anywhere in the scene. Each of the steps has a `Copy Rotation` constraint, targeting the controller empty, which copies only the X rotation (or, whichever axis rotates in your case) from local space to local space.

To control the beam, I added a second empty (the one that's selected in the first image) and parented the beam to it. This empty has a `Copy Rotation` constraint just like the steps. It's important to note the origin point of the beam, it has to be aligned with the empty it's parented to. (You could also parent it to one of the steps, as long as the origin points are aligned on the y and z axes.)

Then, to ensure the beam stays vertical, add a `Limit Rotation` constraint. Have it limit rotation to 0 (on just the X axis, or all axes, doesn't really matter) and make sure you have **world space** selected.

Rotating the controller empty should rotate all steps and move the beam accordingly.

Comment: wow man, Thanks! this is a great help! thank you very much! :)